# What is the fastest way to stream a desktop?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, system.drawing

I'm coding an application much like TeamViewer in C#. My screen transfer is somewhat fast at the moment. I simply divide the screen into chunks and check if their length matches their previous length and so forth. But I can't help but thinking: how can Windows RDP and join.me have such a high speed and still a very low cpu usage?

Thanks.

Comment: RDP operates at the video driver level.  So drawing a rectangle just generates a packet for the rectangle arguments, not all the pixels in the rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to stream the desktop is to not stream the desktop at all.

By having a drawing engine on both the client and server, the server may move a window and transmit a signal to the client that the window has been moved. The window can then be re-drawn on both client and server desktops, effectively mirroring each other without having ever sent any image data.